# Calculate RPM with a quadrature rotary encoder

Tags: arduino

I have written the following code to calculate the RPM of a DC motor using a quadrature rotary encoder and an Arduino Mega:

```
int N3 = 7; //N3 sur la L298N motor shield
int N4 = 8; //N4 sur la L298N motor shield
int ENB = 9; //ENB sur la L298N motor shield
int potPin = A0; //analog pin 0 sur la carte arduino
int valeurLu = 0; //valeur lu du potentiomètre
int valeur_a_ecrire = 0; //valeur à envoyer au moteur
int pin_A_encodeur = 3;
int etat_courant_encodeur = 0;
int etat_precedant_encodeur = 0;

void setup() {
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(3),updatePosition,CHANGE);
  pinMode(N3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(N4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ENB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(pin_A_encodeur, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  valeurLu = analogRead(potPin); 
  valeur_a_ecrire = (255.0/1023.0)*valeurLu;
  digitalWrite(N4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(N3, LOW);
  analogWrite(ENB, valeur_a_ecrire);
  etat_courant_encodeur = digitalRead(pin_A_encodeur);
  Serial.print(valeur_a_ecrire);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(etat_courant_encodeur);
}
```

I'm able to read read information that the encoder sends but it's just a series of ones and zeros (11000111... etc). How can I use this information to calculate the RPM of the motor? My encoder has a resolution of 64 counts per revolution. Thanks in advance for any help on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only reading pin A from the encoder, you will only get 16 impulses per turn.

Here's one way to do it...

```
//...
#define SAMPLE_DELAY (1000)   //  this gets 1 reading per second.
                              //  adjust the delay to fit your needs
#edfine PULSES_PER_TURN (32)  //  32 state changes per turn on 1 line, 
unsigned int pulseCount;
bool lastState;
unsigned int lastTime; 
float rpm;                    // speed in turns/minute, doesn't have to be floating point.

void setup()
{
    // ...
    pinMode(pin_A_encodeur, INPUT);
    lastState = digitalRead(pin_A_encodeur);
}

void loop()
{
    bool curState = digitalRead(pin_A_encodeur);
    if (curState != lastState)
    {
        ++pulseCount;
        lastState = curState;
    }

    if ((unsigned int)millis() - lastTime >= SAMPLE_DELAY)  
    {
         rpm = (pulseCount * (60000.f / ((unsigned int)millis() - lastTime))) / PULSES_PER_TURN;
         pulseCount = 0;
         lastTime = (unsigned int)millis();
    }
    //...
}
```

The casting of the return value of milis() is because we don't need all 32 bits of the millis counter to count to 1000, saves 2 bytes of memory.

By playing with SAMPLE_DELAY, you will notice that there is a trade-off between the stability of the readings, and the sampling frequency. The best value for SAMPLE_DELAY will depend on your application, and the speed range of your motor.

The results depend on what else is in your main loop.  Your loop should not have any delay(), opr you may miss some pulses.  If you cannot avoid that, you should move the pulse detection code in an ISR.

Another way to do it:

```
//...
#define SAMPLE_DELAY (1000)   //  this gets 1 reading per second.
                              //  adjust the delay to fit your needs
#define PULSES_PER_TURN (32)  //  32 state changes per turn on 1 line, 
volatile unsigned int pulseCount;  // note the volatile keyword here.
unsigned int lastTime; 
float rpm;                    // speed in turns/minute, doesn't have to be floating point.

void setup() {
    // ...
    pinMode(pin_A_encodeur, INPUT);
    lastState = digitalRead(pin_A_encodeur);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin_A_encodeur), onPulse, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
    if ((unsigned int)millis() - lastTime >= SAMPLE_DELAY)  
    {
         unsigned int pulses;
         noInterrupts();
         pulses = pulseCount;  // the atmega is 8 bits, you must disable interruts
         pulseCount = 0;       // to read/write 16 bit values accessed by ISR
         interrupts();         // re-enable interrupts.

                               // 60000 milliseconds in 1 minute for rpms.
         rpm = (pulses * (60000.f / ((unsigned int)millis() - lastTime))) / PULSES_PER_TURN;
         lastTime = (unsigned int)millis();
    }
    //...
}

void onPulse() {
    ++pulseCount;
}
```

Note that digital sampling will always lead to some variations in readings.  Remember that if you decide to store RPMs in an integer, you have to use an `unsigned long type`, including for the millis per minute constant `60000ul`, to avoid overflows.

Note also that not all pins are created equal.  only *some* pins that can be linked to an interrupt.  See the arduino doc at: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I've been trying the above solution but I'm not getting the expected result. When I sent a 100% duty cycle command to my motor which is connected to a 12V DC source, I expect the motor's RPM to start from zero (from rest), increase and then attain a constant value (at steady state). But the programme keeps giving me varying values of motor RPM (e.g, 16, 117, 100, 50, ect) . I there something I'm doing right ? Also why the value of 60000.f in the formular: 
    rpm = (pulseCount * (60000.f / ((unsigned int)millis() - lastTime))) / PULSES_PER_TURN;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the updates and the clarifications, I've been able to get a stable value for the motor RPM after steady state is reached. Considering the fact that it's impossible to write arduino data to file from the arduino IDE, I've decided to programme the encoder from within MATLAB, write the encoder data to file which I will later decode in order to determine the RPM of the wheel which is attached to the motor (there's a 100:1 gearbox between the motor and the wheel).

**MATLAB code to command the Arduino board:**

```
  clear;
    clc;
    close all;

    a = arduino('COM5','Uno')
    writeDigitalPin(a, 'D7', 1), writeDigitalPin(a, 'D8', 0)
    writePWMDutyCycle(a,'D9',0.7)

    %Create a file for storing simulation data
    fID = fopen('DemoUnoVmatlab2.txt','w');

    startTime = datetime('now');

    try
        while(1)
            t =  datetime('now') - startTime;

            %Write simulation data to file
            fprintf(fID, '%f\t%f\n', second(datenum(t)), double(readDigitalPin(a,'D2')));
        end
        fclose(fID); 
    catch
        fclose(fID);   
    end
```

**MATLAB Function to treat the acquired data and calculate angular position**

```
function [] = counterVmatlab(signal_A,time)
    count = 0;
    previousState = 0;
    angularPos = 0;
    ppr = 32; % encoder resolution, 32 and NOT 64 because only channel A is used here (see encoder's data sheet)
    gearRatio = 100;
    results = fopen('resultsVmatlab.txt','w');

    for i = 1:length(signal_A)
        presentState = signal_A(i);
        if presentState ~= previousState
            count = count + 1;
            previousState = presentState;
            fprintf(results,'%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n', count, i, angularPos, time(i)); % i ==> at what time did a change in state occur
            angularPos = angularPos + 360/(ppr*gearRatio);
        end   
    end
    fclose(results);
```

By plotting graphs of angular position and angular velocity, I find that the angular velocity varies about a stable value of about 5 degrees/second (see the attached screen capture below). Considering that I have a small motor running on a 12V dc source, I expect the angular velocity to be about 360 degrees/second (which is what one can observe by looking at the motor turning). So I'm wondering if my above decoding algorithm is good? Any help will be very appreciated.

**GRAPH**
[Angular position and angular velocity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUxj9.png)

Comment: At this line:  `angularPos = angularPos + 360/(ppr*gearRatio);`  It the encoder is on the motor shaft, you are calculating the rpm of the wheel.  If the encoder is on the wheel, the motor RPM would be  `angularPos = angularPos + ((360 * gearRatio) / ppr);`

Comment: Also, the graph for angular velocity is all over the place. There are gaps in the graph.  It looks like you are missing some state changes. I don't know if these are due to the way matlab generates the graph.  I wouldn't trust readings with an external program reading the pin remotely.  Have you tried using a diiferent serial monitor like PuTTy to capture the serial output from the arduino to file?  Using Matlab as you do can never be reliable enough to get stable, reliable real-time readings. ...

Comment: ... For best results in capturing  this data to generate the graphs, you should use solution #2 above, do not reset the `pulseCount` counter, and send the difference between two sends, along with the return value from `millis()` over the serial port.